# How to inject entity manager in reusable bundles for unit test?

Tags: php, symfony

i have a reusable bundle, i need to test a Controller and that controller needs `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

My first question is:

How can i instantiate an entity manager with a custom model for use in tests or should i do that ?

Here is service definition for controller:

```
Nedra\RestBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller'
    arguments: [
         "@nedra_rest.registry", 
         "@nedra_rest.request_configuration_factory",
         "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager",
         "@nedra_rest.request_form_factory"
    ]
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

My second question:

How can i test this controller in reusable bundle ? Thank you.

Comment: If you're doing a unit test I would recommend mocking all of those services and not calling them directly.

Comment: @JasonRoman i will do it with mock, thank you.